# Django Admin Template Overriding: Displaying checkboxselectmultiple widget

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-forms

Have 2 tables Domain and Group having one to many relationship.
These tables have many to many relationship with User table

On the User admin interface I am rendering the Group and Domain as CheckboxSelectMultiple 
widgets.

Is it possible to present this in a table form with 2 columns: Domain in one column and the list of groups belonging to the domain in the other column.

I want to override the fieldset template of the admin. However I am having difficulties knowing which methods/properties I can use with an AdminField.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I 100% follow what you are trying to display.

[AdminField](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py#L82) is not documented unfortunately but its a short class, only 18 lines long so you can read it [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py#L82).

I have a feeling you might be trying to step beyond what the admin allows you to do easily, once you are trying to combine more than two different models on the same page things can get a bit messy and you are soon in the business of customizing the admin by writing custom views and templates.

Am I correct in thinking you want to change the list of the objects? Rather than changing the editing/creating page?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and what I did is that I created new html pages and copied the same code from the Admin Template directory HTML pages to my template directory which will be overridden automatically, and then changed the HTML code to what I wanted to be. hope this is useful.